# function that takes iterables and returns a string

Tags: python, iterable

```
def alternate(*args):
    l = ''
    c = 0
    while True:
        try:
            iterable = args[c]
            i = iter(iterable)
            l = l + next(i)
            c = c + 1
        except:
            break
    yield l
```

The alternate generator takes any number of iterables as parameters: it produces the first value from the first parameter, then the first value from the second parameter, ..., then the first value from the last parameter; then the second value from the first parameter, then the second value from the second parameter, ..., then the second value from the last parameter; etc. If any iterable produces no more values, this generator produces no more values. For example:

```
for i in alternate('abcde','fg','hijk'):
    print(i,end='')
```

the answer is:

```
afhbgic
```

when my function takes

```
('abcde','fg','hijk')
```

it returns

```
afh
```

but the correct answer is

```
afhbgic
```

can someone tell me how to fix it? many thanks!

Comment: I just need to get the correct output

Comment: yes, I think so

Comment: How about `zip`ping `args` and then joining the resulting tuples (`''.join()`), and then joining the results of those joins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about solution like this:

```
def alternate(*args):
    l = ''

    # initialize iterators for each argument
    iterators = [iter(it) for it in args]

    # iterate over lengths, using iterators
    while True:
        for it in iterators:
            try:
                l = l + next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                return l

    return l


result = alternate('abcde','fg','hijk')
print(result) # afhbgic
```

Comment: thanks, it did work for the string input. do you know how to make it also work for generator? since generator has no len()

Comment: @jiahuiding I see know what you meen. Let me thing a bit.

Comment: @jiahuiding Edited my anwser. Now it interats until first iterator trhows the StopIteration exception.

Comment: Nice use of iterators!

Answer (score 1):

If you must have a generator, you can make use of `itertools.zip_longest`( `izip_longest` if using Python 2.x):

```
from itertools import zip_longest


def alternate(*args):
    for tup in zip_longest(*args):
        for el in tup:
            if el:
                yield el
            else:
                return
```

**Output:**

```
>>> ''.join(alternate('abcde','fg','hijk'))
'afhbgic'
>>>
```

Otherwise, just use a normal function:

```
from itertools import zip_longest


def alternate(*args):
    s = ''
    for tup in zip_longest(*args):
        for el in tup:
            if el:
                s += el
            else:
                return s
```

**Output:**

```
>>> alternate('abcde','fg','hijk')
'afhbgic'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just like such a madness, sorry :)

```
alternate = lambda args: ''.join(
    filter(
        lambda _, p={1:1}: _ if _ and p else p.clear(),
        reduce(
            lambda x,y: x+y,
            map(None, *args)
        )
    )
)
```